# In statistical mechanics, why is one "allowed" to treat classical systems probabilistically?

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, probability

Is the essential argument that these systems are microscopically chaotic enough that we can approximate their evolution as random (vastly simplifying calculations) and still make accurate experimental predictions? Or are there deeper physical/mathematical foundations?

A related question: how does one interpret the distributions we end up using (e.g. over particle velocities)?

E.g. when we calculate expectation values are we (A) implicitly averaging over an ensemble of universes with different microscopic system configurations? If so, why is it "okay" to make predictions about measurements in one universe from an average over universes? Does one have to invoke some kind of further self-averaging argument? Or (B) are we taking a more Bayesian perspective, where there is only one universe, with the distribution representing our uncertainty over the system state?  If this is the case what other assumptions are made? Should we think of the distributions we manipulate as posteriors, given some prior? If so, what is that prior? Or are (A) and (B) equivalent in some sense?

Or am I thinking about this the wrong way entirely?

Comment: The information theoretic approach (see e.g. the work of Jaynes) seems to answer this question in a quite natural way: You construct, based on limited knowledge of some macro variables, such as $N,V,E$, the "most unbiased" distribution respecting these constraints, i.e. this is "the best" you can do given the limited knowledge. This would correspond to $(B)$ in your question. Whether $A$ is equivalent to $B$ is basically the discussion about frequentist vs. Bayesian interpretation of probabilities.

Comment: The success of statistical mechanics basically shows that for certain macroscopic, reproducible experiments, it suffices to know some macro variables to make predictions (plus some understanding of the micro physics, e.g. if we include spin or not for certain experiments, perhaps the nature of the particles and so on). It does not matter what the state of the system is actually, because in "the most" (read: for practical purposes in all) cases the macroscopic evolution of such systems follows marcoscopic laws.

Comment: Why does it matter? Both your more frequentist version (A) and your more Bayesian version (B) seem like acceptable interpretations to me.